# 'Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

```
toggle.setValue(NSNumber(value: Int(xOr[0])! as Int), forKey: "tag")
```

results in

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Unrelated but never bridge cast a type to the same type. `Int(...)! as Int` is pretty nonsensical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element in xOr at index 0 is either not present (if it is a dictionary) or `nil` (if it is an array).

You should add a check before the element:

```
if xOr.count > 0, let value = xOr[0] as? Int // Maybe remove the count, I don't know whether this is an array or a dictionary. If it is an array, keep the check, if it is a dictionary, keep it.
{
  toggle.setValue(NSNumber(value: value), forKey: "tag")
}
```

Also, `Int(xOr[0])!` already (forcefully) unwraps the value, so you do not need an additional cast to 'Int'.